# Getting id of row just inserted into MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, primary-key

I have my table columns set like this:

```
likes(id, like_message, timestamp)
```

`id` is the primary key that is auto incrementing. This is the SQL that I use to add a row:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `likes` (like_message, timestamp)
        VALUES ('$likeMsg', $timeStamp)";
```

Everything works, but now I need to throw back the `id` attribute of the newly inserted row. For example, if I insert a row and the `id` of that row is `13`, I need to echo out `13` so my AJAX request can pick that up and use it.

Any help would be appreciated, as well as related code samples. Thanks :)

Comment: -1 If you did a quick Internet search of your question "Getting id of row just inserted into MySQL database" using either Google or Bing, the top two search results are the MySQL page describing `LAST_INSERT_ID()` and the PHP.net page describing `mysql_insert_id()`. Please do a quick Internet search next time.

Comment: -1 for extreme duplicate. Even on this site alone, it's not just a google handicap.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$id = mysql_insert_id();
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php

Answer (score 4):

This page will give you lots of good information on the problem:

[MySQL: Getting unique ID](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/getting-unique-id.html)

In PHP:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO foo(blah) values ('blee')");
echo mysql_insert_id();
```

In SQL:

```
INSERT INTO foo (blah) VALUES('blee');

LAST_INSERT_ID()   --now contains your last inserted id
```